# Twilio .sendDigits() not working with WebRTC client out-bound call

Tags: javascript, twilio, dtmf

I am creating a [Twilio WebRTC](https://www.twilio.com/webrtc) soft phone which is almost complete. I need the agent to be able to enter any of 10-digit DTMF touch-tones manually in the course of an out-bound call. I am using the `.sendDigits()` function but it does not produce a touch-tone in a call. All of my other functions work, but I am a bit stuck...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $token; ?>");

  Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
    $("#log").text("Client '<?php echo $clientName ?>' is ready");
  });

  Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
    $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
  });

  Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
    $("#log").text("Successfully established call");
  });

  Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
    $("#log").text("Call ended");
  });

  var connection;

  Twilio.Device.incoming(function(conn) {
      connection = conn;

      $("#number").val(conn.parameters.From);
      var ss= "Incomging Call:\n"+conn.parameters.From;
      $("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);

      //enable the accept button
      $(".accept").prop('disabled', false);
  });

  function accept() {
      connection.accept();
  }

  function call() {
    // get the phone number to connect the call to
    params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
    Twilio.Device.connect(params);
  }

  function hangup() {
    Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
  }

  function senddigits() {

      if (connection!=null)
          connection.sendDigits("1");
  }
</script>
```

I call the function with a simple button...

```
<button onclick="senddigits();">1</button>
```

My code is based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24923993), and the [Twilio.connection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the problem. I just needed to add `connection = conn;` in the connect function...

```
Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
        $("#log").text("Successfully established call");
        connection = conn;
      });
```